# How to overlay Html elements over svg path

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I need to place some html elements over my svg path. How can i do that ?
I looked up for foreignObject but it only allows for whole svg what about the path sections ?

Here is my svg code

```
<svg id="svg" width="50%" height="50%" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linejoin="round" enable_background="new 0 0 1000 589" pretty_print="False" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 271.87 232.08" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="#f9f9f9" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".97063">
        <path d="m109.29 15.045 0.2913-7.5709-3.106-0.0971-21.451-0.97063-21.548-1.3589-48.92-4.2708-3.009-0.29119-0.38825 3.4943-7.2797 75.127-0.67944 7.0856-2.7178 28.634 0.38826 0.0971 13.395 1.2618 1.2618-6.7944 2.4266-1.9413 27.178 2.4266h0.19413l-2.4266-4.7561 12.327 0.87357 30.769 1.7471 19.218 0.87357 3.3002-91.045 0.67944 0.0971 0.0971-2.6207z" data-id="NM" data-name="New Mexico"/>
        <path d="m246.35 13.201-0.19413-2.6207-0.0971-2.5236-0.19413-2.5236-3.6884 0.29119-37.563 1.7471-52.705 0.77651-22.519-0.29119-4.1737-0.0971h-1.553l-6.115-0.19413-1.9413-0.0971-4.0766-0.0971-1.9413-0.0971-0.2913 7.5709-0.0971 2.6207h0.58238l23.489 0.58238 24.848 0.29119 0.29119 33.196 1.7471 5.8238 3.8825 3.6884 4.1737 0.19413 0.87356-1.7471 5.7267 5.2414 7.4739 0.7765 1.3589 1.553 2.7178-1.2618 6.7944 3.2031v1.8442l2.5236-0.0971 2.6207-2.2324 4.8532 3.106 4.562 1.6501 3.106-4.2708 9.9004 4.659 3.6884-3.009 3.009-1.1648 2.4266 0.58238 9.1239-2.6207 4.8532 2.0383 4.3678 2.8148 3.7855 0.67944h0.0971l-0.0971-4.3678-1.0677-26.401-0.0971-4.3678-3.7855-19.607-0.58238-2.7178-0.0971-2.5236z" data-id="OK" data-name="Oklahoma"/>
        <path d="m210.82 227.22-4.659-17.568v3.3002zm-1.0677-30.866-3.3002 6.212-0.38825 2.0383zm2.6207-4.562 3.106-4.0767-2.2324 1.3589zm10.968-9.9004-7.2797 3.7855 2.0383-0.38825zm0.97063-1.3589 2.0383-1.6501-0.7765 0.19413zm-115.12-162.87-0.67944-0.0971-3.3002 91.045-19.218-0.87357-30.769-1.7471-12.327-0.87357 2.4266 4.7561 10.58 10.58 6.0179 7.0856 7.9592 5.9208 5.6297 10.289 2.1354 10.774 4.562 3.009 3.5913 3.9796 5.1443 1.8442 7.4739 4.7561 3.3972 1.2618 4.659-4.659 1.456-4.9502 2.4266-4.7561 7.5709-3.009 2.9119 1.4559 8.4445 0.67945 7.668 4.7561 5.2414 0.97063-1.456 2.7178 3.009 1.9413 2.8148 3.3972 0.58238 3.5913 1.8442 2.4266 4.2708 10.289 4.2708 3.5913 3.3002 5.4355 4.1737 4.2708 1.8442 0.58238 1.553 11.065 4.562 2.5236 0.19412 3.4943 1.1648-0.29119 7.9592 9.7063 3.9796 0.87357 5.0473 3.009h7.765l5.6297 3.106 6.6974-1.4559-3.009-2.8148-2.7178-8.1533-1.0677-7.0856-1.553-2.3295 0.67944-4.7561-2.0383-0.19413-2.7178-4.4649 3.106 3.3002 3.5913-1.2618 1.9413-5.1444-3.8825-5.2414 5.8238 0.67944 2.7178-4.1737-0.38825-1.456 2.4266-3.2031-0.58238 2.8148 2.7178-2.1354-1.0677-3.7855 3.4943 1.8442 4.4649-2.5236-4.3678-4.562 2.7178 1.0677 5.0473 0.29119 6.6003-1.456 7.3768-4.9502 4.4649-3.6884 0.67944-2.7178 2.7178-2.8148-1.456-4.659 0.29119-2.9119 4.8532-2.1354-0.38826 5.1444h2.9119l-3.2031 2.7178 12.909-6.7944 2.1354-0.0971 1.3589-6.212h0.38826l1.4559-3.5913 0.67944-11.065 0.87357-4.4649-2.5236-7.9592-3.106-5.4355-0.0971-2.6207-3.2031-4.4649-1.9413-18.733-0.0971-2.3295-0.19413-2.4266-0.58238-8.5416-5.8238 0.19413-1.456-1.553-0.29119-0.0971h-0.0971l-3.7855-0.67944-4.3678-2.8148-4.8532-2.0383-9.1239 2.6207-2.4266-0.58238-3.009 1.1648-3.6884 3.009-9.9004-4.659-3.106 4.2708-4.562-1.6501-4.8532-3.106-2.6207 2.2324-2.5236 0.0971v-1.8442l-6.7944-3.2031-2.7178 1.2618-1.3589-1.553-7.4739-0.7765-5.7267-5.2414-0.87356 1.7471-4.1737-0.19413-3.8825-3.6884-1.7471-5.8238-0.29119-33.196-24.848-0.29119-23.489-0.58238h-0.58238z" data-id="TX" data-name="Texas"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Where do you need to place your HTML elements? In the middle of every path?

Comment: @enxaneta yes i want to add them in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the center of a path in pixels in a resizable svg element. For this you need:

1. to find the center of a path in svg units
2. convert the svg units in pixels
3. repeat on resize

Please read the comments on my code.

In my code the div `#label` is just a point. If you need to add text to the div you'll need to take in account the width and the height of the div.

```js
// the values of the svg viewBox
svgVB = { x: 0, y: 0, w: 271.87, h: 232.08 };
//the bounding box for the path id="NM"
let BB = NM.getBBox();
//the center of the path in svg units
let center = {};
center.x = BB.x + BB.width / 2;
center.y = BB.y + BB.height / 2;
//the center of the path in html units
let htmlCenter = {};
// a function to get the position of the div
function positionDiv() {
  //first get the size and the position of the svg element
  let SVGClientRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  //calculate the htmlCenter x
  htmlCenter.x = map(
    center.x,
    svgVB.x,
    svgVB.w,
    SVGClientRect.x,
    SVGClientRect.x + SVGClientRect.width
  );
  //calculate the htmlCenter y
  htmlCenter.y = map(
    center.y,
    svgVB.y,
    svgVB.h,
    SVGClientRect.y,
    SVGClientRect.y + SVGClientRect.height
  );
  // set the styles for the label
  label.style.left = htmlCenter.x + "px";
  label.style.top = htmlCenter.y + "px";
}

//call the positionDiv function 
positionDiv();
//call the positionDiv function on resize
window.setTimeout(function() {
  positionDiv();
  window.addEventListener("resize", positionDiv, false);
}, 15);




function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#label {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="50%" height="50%" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linejoin="round" enable_background="new 0 0 1000 589" pretty_print="False" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 271.87 232.08" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="#f9f9f9" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".97063">
        <path d="m109.29 15.045 0.2913-7.5709-3.106-0.0971-21.451-0.97063-21.548-1.3589-48.92-4.2708-3.009-0.29119-0.38825 3.4943-7.2797 75.127-0.67944 7.0856-2.7178 28.634 0.38826 0.0971 13.395 1.2618 1.2618-6.7944 2.4266-1.9413 27.178 2.4266h0.19413l-2.4266-4.7561 12.327 0.87357 30.769 1.7471 19.218 0.87357 3.3002-91.045 0.67944 0.0971 0.0971-2.6207z" id="NM" data-name="New Mexico"/>
        <path d="m246.35 13.201-0.19413-2.6207-0.0971-2.5236-0.19413-2.5236-3.6884 0.29119-37.563 1.7471-52.705 0.77651-22.519-0.29119-4.1737-0.0971h-1.553l-6.115-0.19413-1.9413-0.0971-4.0766-0.0971-1.9413-0.0971-0.2913 7.5709-0.0971 2.6207h0.58238l23.489 0.58238 24.848 0.29119 0.29119 33.196 1.7471 5.8238 3.8825 3.6884 4.1737 0.19413 0.87356-1.7471 5.7267 5.2414 7.4739 0.7765 1.3589 1.553 2.7178-1.2618 6.7944 3.2031v1.8442l2.5236-0.0971 2.6207-2.2324 4.8532 3.106 4.562 1.6501 3.106-4.2708 9.9004 4.659 3.6884-3.009 3.009-1.1648 2.4266 0.58238 9.1239-2.6207 4.8532 2.0383 4.3678 2.8148 3.7855 0.67944h0.0971l-0.0971-4.3678-1.0677-26.401-0.0971-4.3678-3.7855-19.607-0.58238-2.7178-0.0971-2.5236z" id="OK" data-name="Oklahoma"/>
        <path d="m210.82 227.22-4.659-17.568v3.3002zm-1.0677-30.866-3.3002 6.212-0.38825 2.0383zm2.6207-4.562 3.106-4.0767-2.2324 1.3589zm10.968-9.9004-7.2797 3.7855 2.0383-0.38825zm0.97063-1.3589 2.0383-1.6501-0.7765 0.19413zm-115.12-162.87-0.67944-0.0971-3.3002 91.045-19.218-0.87357-30.769-1.7471-12.327-0.87357 2.4266 4.7561 10.58 10.58 6.0179 7.0856 7.9592 5.9208 5.6297 10.289 2.1354 10.774 4.562 3.009 3.5913 3.9796 5.1443 1.8442 7.4739 4.7561 3.3972 1.2618 4.659-4.659 1.456-4.9502 2.4266-4.7561 7.5709-3.009 2.9119 1.4559 8.4445 0.67945 7.668 4.7561 5.2414 0.97063-1.456 2.7178 3.009 1.9413 2.8148 3.3972 0.58238 3.5913 1.8442 2.4266 4.2708 10.289 4.2708 3.5913 3.3002 5.4355 4.1737 4.2708 1.8442 0.58238 1.553 11.065 4.562 2.5236 0.19412 3.4943 1.1648-0.29119 7.9592 9.7063 3.9796 0.87357 5.0473 3.009h7.765l5.6297 3.106 6.6974-1.4559-3.009-2.8148-2.7178-8.1533-1.0677-7.0856-1.553-2.3295 0.67944-4.7561-2.0383-0.19413-2.7178-4.4649 3.106 3.3002 3.5913-1.2618 1.9413-5.1444-3.8825-5.2414 5.8238 0.67944 2.7178-4.1737-0.38825-1.456 2.4266-3.2031-0.58238 2.8148 2.7178-2.1354-1.0677-3.7855 3.4943 1.8442 4.4649-2.5236-4.3678-4.562 2.7178 1.0677 5.0473 0.29119 6.6003-1.456 7.3768-4.9502 4.4649-3.6884 0.67944-2.7178 2.7178-2.8148-1.456-4.659 0.29119-2.9119 4.8532-2.1354-0.38826 5.1444h2.9119l-3.2031 2.7178 12.909-6.7944 2.1354-0.0971 1.3589-6.212h0.38826l1.4559-3.5913 0.67944-11.065 0.87357-4.4649-2.5236-7.9592-3.106-5.4355-0.0971-2.6207-3.2031-4.4649-1.9413-18.733-0.0971-2.3295-0.19413-2.4266-0.58238-8.5416-5.8238 0.19413-1.456-1.553-0.29119-0.0971h-0.0971l-3.7855-0.67944-4.3678-2.8148-4.8532-2.0383-9.1239 2.6207-2.4266-0.58238-3.009 1.1648-3.6884 3.009-9.9004-4.659-3.106 4.2708-4.562-1.6501-4.8532-3.106-2.6207 2.2324-2.5236 0.0971v-1.8442l-6.7944-3.2031-2.7178 1.2618-1.3589-1.553-7.4739-0.7765-5.7267-5.2414-0.87356 1.7471-4.1737-0.19413-3.8825-3.6884-1.7471-5.8238-0.29119-33.196-24.848-0.29119-23.489-0.58238h-0.58238z" id="TX" data-name="Texas"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<div id="label"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an id to your path

```
<path id="my-text" .......... />
```

aftet that, inside your `svg tags` put:

```
  <text>
      <textPath xlink:href="#text">text on a path</textPath>  
  </text>
```

you use the same id you used for that path in the `href=""`

Hope this helps!

this article also may help you out! https://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-text-on-a-path-part-1/

for putting elements in your svg: 
The only way i found was using `<foreignObject>`

example:

```
<svg>
....
....
<foreignObject>

<div> your content</div>

</foreignObject>

</svg>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject this article can you more about that. There are ways yo position with x and y attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man, I have a question before i try this out. I guess this will only work for text ? because i want to add div elements not text.

Comment: I added someting to my answer. I don't think it specifically can be used for paths but definitely for your svg! Just have to find the right positions with the attributes found in the article: x y height and width

Comment: thanks once again but using foreign object will not help because there will be n number of paths and n number of html elements associated to that path and i guess giving X Y will not allow the view to be responsive please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: It actually scales pretty well together with your svg! i can make a little codepen if you want?

Comment: I tried a few things : https://codepen.io/YilmazTut/pen/XQXYyz a few divs and a <p> and it all scales well. Try resizing the browser when you are in the pen